# patches between diverging git forks

Tags: git, github, diff

A while ago I created a project on github. The project grew in followers, and with time another active developer joined it. The problem is that we had different needs and approaches, and he ended up forking the project and now runs a parallel fork. The forks, while achieving the same results and often sharing bugs, are starting to look less and less like each other internally, think Putty vs Mintty.

He continues fixing various project issues in his own fork and informs me when he does, which is very helpful. He even goes through the issue list for the main fork, and addresses the bugs mentioned there. Unfortunately, he doesn't like doing pull requests, so unless I manually go through his commits myself, the issues will not get fixed in the main fork. This happens quite often.

This is not a typical fork, however, there are a few things that prevent github's internal diff tool from generating a patch that I could ever hope to apply cleanly:

- Despite similarities in code base, he moved some files around and renamed others. A human can often see where to inject the code, a patch generator that simply looks at +/- 3 lines can't.
- The project is a transcompiler, and comes with pre-generated version of itself, these "compiled" files will never match and should be ignored by the patcher.

If I could either inform the patcher manually (in a config file) which files in my codebase map to which in his or have a diff tool capable of tracking/discarding previous commits intelligently to get the projects more similar in context of a given patch, that would help save time tremendously. Is there something along these lines?